# Facebook: Can't publish on user feed in test mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a Facebook app in test mod and I want to publish on the test user's wall.

this is the link where the user register and accept the permissions:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&client_id=MY_APP_ID&display=popup&redirect_uri=THE_URL&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions`

After that I am getting an some sort of a token, using this token I am doing the following request to the graph:

`/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=".$token`

the token coming back is now being used by me to get the user's details from the graph:

`/me/?$user_access_token&fields=name,age_range,id,email,gender,currency,locale,timezone"`

I am getting in result all the fields listed above. (**one strange thing, the id coming back is not the test user's public id, the other field are correct...**)

when I want to post so someones wall I am running this int the graph:

`/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials`

the token coming back will be used here:

```
    $token = self::getAccessToken($app_id,$app_secret); 
    $post_array = array();
    $post_array['access_token'] = $token;
    $post_array['message'] = urlencode($message);
    $post_array['link'] = urlencode($link);
    $res = self::post("https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/feed?",$post_array);// the user id might be wrong?
```

and I am getting the following error: 
`{"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"EO5WvMfYYgC"}}`

What can it be?
the fact that I am in test mod?
or maybe the user's ID i got back is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What permissions has the user granted to the app?

Comment: @WizKid see the first url i posted here (`scope=email%2Cpublish_actions`)

Comment: That URL means you _tried to ask_ for the permissions, not that the user actually granted them. Was the user even asked for publishing permission in the dialog? If the user doesn’t have a role in the app, you of course need to get that permission reviewed first.

Comment: @CBroe, since its a test mod, I am the user (in my other account), I have granted the other account with the permissions. so I must be able to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is correct, you only get an "App Scoped ID". You are not supposed to use the global/public ID anymore, and you should use `/me/feed` for posting, not `/user-id/feed`. You can only post on the wall of the authorized user anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I know that i can only post on my authorized users wall. but, where to i tell to facebook which user to post in? "/me/feed" has no indication about the user, for some reason it is not mentioned on the api guide either.

Comment: /me is the current user, depending on the user access token. just use it.

Comment: what's wrong with this: `curl -X POST  https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=944609325668755%7Cf1lj14epP1Hgxj_OpyczE67-_RM&message=test+message&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com` I am getting the following error from the graph  : `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user`

Comment: that does not look like an access token - but you should NEVER post an access token anywhere anyway. always keep it secret.